# How to put a form (2 dropdowns and button) centered on one line

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I've looked at other similar questions of this, but I've had no success incorporating their ideas into my code since it's so different than question started with. What's stranger is that in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K2Zzh/621/) my code is able to be centered but I can't get it on the same line where as in my project I can get it on the same line but not get it centered.

For some reason I don't understand, the width of the row element is far bigger than any of the elements. And neither `100%` nor `auto` removes the empty space from the row: [image]

html:

```
<form method="POST" class="dropdownForms">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1">Choose 1st option</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
          <option>1st dropdown</option>
          <!-- more options here-->
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1">Choose 2nd option</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
          <option>2nd dropdown</option>
          <!-- more options here -->
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

css:

```
.dropdownForms{
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none; 
  display: inline   
}

.row{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center
}

.col-md-3{
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px
}

.form-control {
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}

.form-group {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

edit: After using Arashtad Ltd's changes it does work in jsFiddle, but in my project it still looks weird:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to code this much. Only these two pieces get you to the result you're looking for:

```
form {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.row,
.col-md-3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Please see the running code at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arashtad/u52busjd/)

Comment: Sorry I'm still new with html and css, your fix does make it work on jsFiddle but my project has the label lines and dropdowns stacking on each other, which wasn't happening before, do you how to fix this? See my edit on the question.

Comment: So you need to paste all the codes you think are effecting the output. Otherwise nobody can find the problem. The code I suggested works in a regular situation. But if you got other codes effecting the form, SOF guys need to see it first :-)

Comment: I've disabled the rest of my custom css. So the css values are either coming from what I've shown or bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

On top of Arashtad Ltd's answer, I changed `col-md-3` to `col` and added more `col` elements to encapsulate each `label` and `select`.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u52busjd/1/)

And that solved my problem for my project.